# Как задействовать setContent в новом классе?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Я начал изучать jetpack compose. Я сделал переход между активити (с помощью intent). Вот только когда у меня открывается новое активити, так как там нету setContent, то оно пустое.

Как мне поместить `setContent {}` в новый класс?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: С чем конкретно у вас возникла проблема? От какого класса наследуется ваша активити? Вы пробовали написать `setContent` в метод `onCreate`? Если да, то какой получили результат? Напишите все необходимые детали непосредственно [в вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1465021/edit).

Answer (score 0):

1. Проверьте в файле `build.gradle`, что у вас подключен compose:

   ```
   android {
       ...
       composeOptions {
           kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.2'
       }
   }
   ```
2. Проверьте в том же файле, что у вас есть нужные зависимости:

   ```
   dependencies {
       ...
       implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1'
       implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.3.0'
   }
   ```
3. Отнаследуйте вашу активити от [`ComponentActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity) и теперь можете использовать [`setContent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/compose/package-summary#(androidx.activity.ComponentActivity).setContent(androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionContext,kotlin.Function0)), чтобы погрузиться в мир compose:

   ```kotlin
   package com.example

   import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
   import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
   import androidx.compose.material.Text

   class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

       override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
           setContent {
               Text("Hello Compose!")
           }
       }

   }
   ```
4. Кроме этого, проверьте, что используете актуальные версии [compose.compiler](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose), [compose.material](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose) и [activity-compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity).